# kdensity normalised by the total number of points

Tags: gnuplot

I have the next plot of a KDE density plot of a dataset in file `AAFPStable.dat` which has 5 columns.
I only want to use the first for the plot.

```
set encoding iso_8859_1
set key right top font "Helvetica,17"
set ylabel "Density" font "Helvetica,18"
set xlabel "Minutes" font "Helvetica,18"
set xtics font "Helvetica,16"
set ytics font "Helvetica,16"
set title "Event 1" font "Helvetica, 18"
set size 1, 1.2
set terminal postscript eps enhanced 
set grid
set key spacing 1.5
set key box linestyle 1 width 3
lfps = system("cat AAFPStable.dat | wc -l") 
set output "event1-gnu.eps"
plot [0:150][] "AAFPStable.dat" using 1:(1) smooth kdensity bandwidth 2.5 lw 2 title "FPS"
```

The problem is that now the figure shows de KDE density plot but on the y-axis, it shows the number of occurrences. I would like to have the normalized density plot showing probability densities between 0 and 1. The command says that the second column should be 1/(count of points). The value of `lfps` is the number of rows of the file. I have tasted to change 1:(1) by 1:(1/lfps) but it does not work. I would not like to generate an intermediate file with the first column of AAFPS.dat and add a second with the value of 1/lfps.

How could I indicate gnuplot to plot the normalize KDE density plot?

Thank you for your help
Regards

Answer (score 0):

It works with

```
plot [0:150][] "AAFPStable.dat" using 1:(1./lfps) smooth kdensity bandwidth 2.5 lw 2 title "FPS"
```

Thanks